# Extract the different element of a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, element, list-comparison

In a list of three elements I want to find the element of a list that is different from the other two.
For example I have `L=[3,3,1]` and I want to extract the number 1. At first I was thinking about using `set()` so I can compare it with a list but then I got stuck again in this code:

```
S=set(L)
c1=0
c2=0
for k in L:
    for i in S:
        if k==i:
            c1+=1
            v1=k
        else:
            c2+=1
            v2=k
if c1<c2:
    print (v1)
else:
    print (v2)
```

I tried to count how many times they appear so I can be sure with c1 and c2 will have a different value but then I realized v1 and v2 were completely wrong.

Comment: Try counting the elements and storing the counts in a dictionary

Comment: Is it always ints?

Comment: @DaniMesejo pretty interesting, possibly that will work but i am looking for a quicker way if that's possible, but still thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the rarest?

```
>>> min(L, key=L.count)
1
```

Or if they're all ints, make the duplicate pair cancel each other with xor:

```
>>> L[0] ^ L[1] ^ L[2]
1
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know the list contains exactly three items and two of them are equal, it might be easier to just check things explicitly:

```py
if L[0] == L[1]:
    print(L[2])
elif L[0] == L[2]:
    print(L[1])
else:
    print(L[0])
```

Comment: in Python place 'else if' you have to write 'elif'

Comment: @Danis God catch. Momentary lapse of concentration on my side. Edited and fixed.